# How to use CSS \cubic-bezier to implement sine function?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm going to implement CSS width animation in sine function like:

[image]

But with `cubic-bezier`, I can only set four parameters like `transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.695, 0.015, 1.000, 0.275);`.

Is it position to achieve this using CSS animation? Or else how to do this in JS?

Comment: `cubic-bezier` is not animatable. Take a look http://www.humblesoftware.com/demos/trig for javascript solution

Answer (score 3):

You can imitate sine function using `cubic-bezier()`

Have a look at this resource for sine approximation: [Sine approximation using cubic Bézier curves](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mtdihhagsx)

Using 4 keyframes and `cubic-bezier()` with values:

```
cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1)
cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1)
cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1)
cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1)
```

will move an object with sine function trajectory.

I made a demo for your case. Pure CSS solution, please have a look:

### DEMO

```css
.box {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: royalblue;

    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation:
            sine1-1 0.3s 1 0s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1),
            sine1-2 0.3s 1 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1),
            sine1-3 0.3s 1 0.6s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1),
            sine1-4 0.3s 1 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1),
            sine2-1 0.3s 1 1.2s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1),
            sine2-2 0.3s 1 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1),
            sine2-3 0.3s 1 1.8s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1),
            sine2-4 0.3s 1 2.1s cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1),
            sine3-1 0.3s 1 2.4s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.3642,1),
            sine3-2 0.3s 1 2.7s cubic-bezier(0.6358,0,1,1);
}

@keyframes sine1-1 {
    0% {transform: translateY(0)}
    100% {transform: translateY(-100px)}
}

@keyframes sine1-2 {
    0% {transform: translateY(-100px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes sine1-3 {
    0% {transform: translateY(0)}
    100% {transform: translateY(80px)}
}

@keyframes sine1-4 {
    0% {transform: translateY(80px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes sine2-1 {
    0% {transform: translateY(0)}
    100% {transform: translateY(-60px)}
}

@keyframes sine2-2 {
    0% {transform: translateY(-60px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes sine2-3 {
    0% {transform: translateY(0)}
    100% {transform: translateY(40px)}
}

@keyframes sine2-4 {
    0% {transform: translateY(40px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0)}
}

@keyframes sine3-1 {
    0% {transform: translateY(0)}
    100% {transform: translateY(-20px)}
}

@keyframes sine3-2 {
    0% {transform: translateY(-20px)}
    100% {transform: translateY(0)}
}

.horizontal {
    animation: move-horizontal 3s 1 linear;
}

@keyframes move-horizontal {
    0% {transform: translateX(0)}
    100% {transform: translateX(400px)}
}

.wrap {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

.margin {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="margin"></div>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="horizontal">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```